# How to ON or OFF audio recording using MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediarecorder

I'm implement one demo Video and Audio recording using `MediaRecorder`

Download the demo from hear : **[Android MediaRecorder Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder)**

There is one method **`prepareVideoRecorder()`** in `MainActivity.java`. in this method initialization and **set Source** Audio and video like:

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
```

Now i want to audio **ON** or **OFF** functionality.

For that i'll tried like this :

```
 if (!AppSetting.getValue(activity, Config.AUDIO, false)) {
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        }else {
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        }
```

But app is Crash with below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(Native Method)
```

So how to i solve this error or there is another solution for Audio **ON** or **OFF**:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution:

---

If my switch is **ON** then **`if`** part execute(Sound is record). if my switch is **OFF** then `else` part execute(Sound do not record).

---

```
if (AppSetting.getValue(activity, Config.AUDIO, false)) {
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(duration);
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
        } else {
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
            mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(duration);
        }
```

---